# How do I print columns selected from a query in MySQL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

This confounds me. I for example I have a certain record in a table *yes* in MySQL.

```
     | name | pizza |  burger | fries |  sundae  |
   1 | boo  |   0   |    0    |   1   |    2     |
```

To print this table MANUALLY:

```
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM yes WHERE name = 'boo' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $row['fries'];
    echo $row['sundae'];
}
```

So, I know only fries would have a non-zero value, so its the only column value I echoed. Would there be any way to loop through all the columns in the query without echoing the columns manually?

For example, if I had 100 food items and only 69 had a non-zero value, does that mean I'd have to echo one by one all the columns in the loop?

Ideally, I'd want the PHP to show only the name and the food item ordered that has a non-zero value.

The output would be something like 
Boo, you have ordered 1 fries, 2 sundaes, n food, and so on.

Working with MySQL and PHP.

Comment: Why don't you know the name of the columns?

Comment: Ah, yes. If I originally have 100 columns, then 30 after the query, I would know which 30 it is, but I do think it's inefficient to type all 30 columns in the loop. I'm looking to automate the process.

Comment: Either you get every column or only the columns you requested. You don't get random columns so you'll always know what columns you're getting. When you use a `WHERE` clause you're reducing the number of **rows** returned, not columns.

Comment: I don't get it, so you want to get columns that's been selected?

Comment: Yes, I'd want to get the all values from the record except ones with zero values.

Comment: I read this a few times and still have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe give a little more context of what you're really trying to do, and more realistic examples instead of stuff like `sucks` `yes` and `burger`.

Comment: I've edited the question to the best of my ability.

Comment: Looping with a foreach($var as $key => $value) would allow you to echo the column names using the $key so then you wouldn't have to type them out. Not sure if you are looking for that but its a simple method to print the names for each column returned. You could also just wrap it in a if($var != null || $var != 0) really however you wanted to do it.

Comment: Another thought you could also specify in your query to select only values greater than 0 so that you arent left with data you dont want.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this. Hope it helps though.

Take note that **rooms is column name** and **dorm is a table name**

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT rooms FROM dorm";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$get_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while (list($column_name, $column_value) = each($get_data)) {
    if ($column_value != 0) {
        echo $column_name; //Outputs Column name
        echo $column_value; //Outputs Column Value
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: It doesn't quite cut it sorry. I've rephrased the question to better clarify my problem.